# How do I intercept a filter on either RadGrid or ASPxGridView for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, telerik-grid, aspxgridview

I need help choosing between Telerik RadGrid and DevExpress ASPxGridView for Asp.Net based on unique filtering requirements. The data lives in denormalized Vax files. All data access is via Sql Server stored procedures calling ODBC Connx queries to the flat files. Stored procedure parameters are used to filter the data. Without any filter thousand of records are returned.

I've successfully displayed all records on two test ASP.net pages, one with DevExpress ASPxGridVIew and the other with Telerik's RadGrid. In code I databind each grid to the stored procedure that returns over 26,000 rows. The sproc is called via an Entity Framework function import that fills an `IEnumerable<Customer>` which becomes the datasource of each respective grid. I'm able to use the filter features of both grids and they seem to work nicely.

My problem is that before the grid filter is applied all of the thousands of rows are returned from the stored procedure. I'd like to intercept the grid's filter parameters and apply them to my stored procedure parameters. That way far fewer records will be accessed.

Can this be done with either 3rd party grid and if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it can be achieved using a RadFilter to the RadGrid. One [example here.](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/filter/examples/integration/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid)

But in general, looks like you'd need to add a handler to ItemCommand, and perform the appropriate filter based on the CommandName, for example. You could then just rebind the data.

Answer (score 0):

The Rad Filter will also allow you to use it without being directly tied to another control or datasource.  The filter has an option to extract a filter expression in many different forms (linq provider is one of them).  You can then apply that expression to your datasource.  We are doing something similar.  We have a page where we dynamically create the rad filter with the types of fields and filter options.  The user then uses the rad filter UI to create the filter based on the desired fields, then we extract a filter expression we can apply to a datatable that is created on the page that shows the data.

Here is the code for extracting the filter expression from the filter:

```
var provider = new RadFilterSqlQueryProvider();
provider.ProcessGroup(myRadFilter.RootGroup);

var sqlFilterExpression = provider.Result;
```